# I want a R function to count top 3 ingredients in recipes dataframe

Tags: r

My table looks like this:

```
"id","name","area","ingredients"
53010,"Lamb Tzatziki Burgers","Greek","Bulgur Wheat, Lamb Mince, Cumin, Coriander, Paprika, Garlic, Olive Oil, Bun, Cucumber, Greek Yogurt, Mint"
52909,"Tarte Tatin","French","Puff Pastry, Plain Flour, Braeburn Apples, Caster Sugar, Butter, Creme Fraiche"
52871,"Yaki Udon","Japanese","Udon Noodles, Sesame Seed Oil, Onion, Cabbage, Shiitake Mushrooms, Spring Onions, Mirin, Soy Sauce, Caster Sugar, Worcestershire Sauce"
52875,"Chicken Ham and Leek Pie","British","Chicken Stock, Chicken Breast, Butter, Leek, Garlic, Plain Flour, Milk, White Wine, Double Cream, Ham, Sea Salt, Pepper, Plain Flour, Butter, Free-range Egg, Beaten, Cold Water, Free-range Egg, Beaten"
53019,"Pierogi (Polish Dumplings)","Polish","Butter, Chopped Onion, Sauerkraut, Butter, Chopped Onion, Potatoes, Eggs, Sour Cream, Flour, Salt, Baking Powder"
```

I want the following output

```
"name", "ouput"
"butter", 5
"plain flour", 3
```

Answer (score 2):

split the column at the `,` followed by any spaces with `separate_rows`, then get the frequency `count` with `sort = TRUE` and then use `slice_head` or  use `slice_max`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  separate_rows(ingredients, sep = ",\\s*") %>% 
  count(ingredients, sort = TRUE) %>%   
  slice_head(n = 2)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  ingredients     n
  <chr>       <int>
1 Butter          5
2 Plain Flour     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(53010L, 52909L, 52871L, 52875L, 53019L), 
    name = c("Lamb Tzatziki Burgers", "Tarte Tatin", "Yaki Udon", 
    "Chicken Ham and Leek Pie", "Pierogi (Polish Dumplings)"), 
    area = c("Greek", "French", "Japanese", "British", "Polish"
    ), ingredients = c("Bulgur Wheat, Lamb Mince, Cumin, Coriander, Paprika, Garlic, Olive Oil, Bun, Cucumber, Greek Yogurt, Mint", 
    "Puff Pastry, Plain Flour, Braeburn Apples, Caster Sugar, Butter, Creme Fraiche", 
    "Udon Noodles, Sesame Seed Oil, Onion, Cabbage, Shiitake Mushrooms, Spring Onions, Mirin, Soy Sauce, Caster Sugar, Worcestershire Sauce", 
    "Chicken Stock, Chicken Breast, Butter, Leek, Garlic, Plain Flour, Milk, White Wine, Double Cream, Ham, Sea Salt, Pepper, Plain Flour, Butter, Free-range Egg, Beaten, Cold Water, Free-range Egg, Beaten", 
    "Butter, Chopped Onion, Sauerkraut, Butter, Chopped Onion, Potatoes, Eggs, Sour Cream, Flour, Salt, Baking Powder"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```